# Can my employer ask LinkedIn to delete posts of mine?

Tags: employer-relations, linkedin

Let's assume my LinkedIn account shows the name of my current employer (as most accounts do). Can the employer ask LinkedIn to delete posts of mine which they don't want to see associated with the company? Can they do this even if the posts are by no means offending or inappropriate? Does this right differ by country?

Comment: Rather than contacting LinkedIn, I feel like any company would go directly to you during cases like these and ask you to take down those posts. Though you'd have to have posted something really concerning to the company for them to want it taken down.

Comment: OT, but as a contractor I never have the current client on there. I've been burnt in the past with scummy recruiters phoning them up to offer their own contractors more cheaply or actually and falsely disparaging me.

Comment: Have you observed posts of your own being deleted on LinkedIn?  Have you checked with anyone other than yourself to confirm that they are not offensive or inappropriate?  (Most people don't usually decide to post something they themselves realize will be offensive.)  Assuming this is the case, what leads you to believe it was your employer who requested they be deleted?

Comment: Probably not. Imagine if one person could request to have another person's content modified or removed and imaging if LinkedIn would honor such a request. Your employer has no legal authority to have LinkedIn do anything with your posts. They can ask, but it's highly doubtful that LinkedIn would comply.

Answer (score 9):

They can certainly ask. Whether or not LinkedIn will comply, only LinkedIn can say for sure. Or waiting to see.

But, since your employer objects to these posts, do you really want to upset them?

Remove the posts yourself, apologizing is not necessary, but would not hurt.

Then ask you employer for a clear, ***written*** policy on what you may post when their name is visible and will appear to be associated with it.

Comment: Also: figure out who wants you post removed and talk to them. A written pollicy is all good and well but if this is someone up high enough it is better to go and have a dialog

Comment: I upvoted your comment, but am really in two minds. If my M.D wants my post gone, he probably just wants it gone & not to have a chat with underlings. I guess I depends on your knowledge of whomever it was.

Comment: You should ask the employer for a written policy **before** removing the posts. And if the posts are not against a written policy you should not remove them. If the employer insist, you should update my CV and begin looking for a new job since in this case you are working for a employer that does not follow the rules **he** wrote, which IMHO is a big red flag.

Comment: @Mawg, really depends on company culture but if you have a boss like that, yeah, no explanation needed.

Comment: @Gianluca any sensible policy includes a "at discretion of management" clause so playing rules lawyer will get you nowhere.

Comment: @Borgh maybe. But never found it. Every time I have to accept a policy, it was very specific without any space for interpretation. Such clause can be easily used against the employer.

Answer (score 2):

## Absent legal weight behind the request or breaking of Terms Of Service, it is unlikely that LinkedIn will simply delete the content of other people at someone else's request.

Deleting something simply because another company doesn't like it will ultimately have a chilling effect on the rest of the site userbase. This can get people to leave in droves and promote the use of competitors. As such, LinkedIn doesn't even do this for Microsoft, the current owners of LinkedIn.

The employer can potentially get it deleted under a legal objection, but LinkedIn is no YouTube in that not everything is 100% automated and customer services do exist, so such a legal challenge is not automatically guaranteed and may need actual weight behind it beyond a claim.

Answer (score 1):

They can try...

In practice, it'll be difficult and your employer would need to provide a very good reason for wanting your content to be edited.

LinkedIn's editing policy will be governed by LinkedIn, so you'll need to ask them directly, or use the official support forum to ask this question.